# AWS - Can't create S3 event notification to SNS topic from specific bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, amazon-policy

I'm trying to create S3 event notification to SNS topic from an existing S3 bucket. I'm receiving "Unable to validate the following destination configurations".

Initially I thought the issue was with the SNS topic Access Policy and tried different troubleshooting suggestions, such as this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjSW75YsBMM, but nothing worked.

I'm using the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "example-ID",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Example SNS topic policy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "SNS:Publish"
            ],
            "Resource": "SNS-topic-ARN",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnLike": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:bucket-name"
                },
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceAccount": "bucket-owner-account-id"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I decided to focus on the S3 bucket part of the equation and created brand new bucket with exactly the same configuration, switched the SourceArn in the policy with the new bucket's arn and the event notification was successfully created.

What could be the reason for a given SNS topic with a given policy to work with one S3 bucket, but not with another?

Comment: Is the existing s3 bucket created in the same region as the sns topic?

Comment: @ErikAsplund, yes, both are in us-west-2 region

Comment: Setting up the destination configuration, do you use the console of some kind of IaC?
If you use the console do you specify the target with the arn or by picking it from the drops down menus?

Comment: @ErikAsplund, I'm using the console and I've tried both with the arn and with the dropdown menu, there seems to be any difference - both work for the new bucket and both don't for the old one

Comment: Can it be that another aws account created the s3 bucket in this account?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have event notifications enabled for the S3 bucket? There are several types of [events that can be configured for a bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-enable-disable-notification-intro.html).

It looks like for SNS, you'd need the NotificationConfiguration of the bucket itself to include a TopicConfiguration. Maybe this is enabled for one bucket but not the other?

[Related walkthrough is here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html)

```
 <NotificationConfiguration>
  <TopicConfiguration>
     <Id>optional-id-string</Id>
     <Topic>sns-topic-arn</Topic>
     <Event>event-type</Event>
     <Event>event-type</Event>
      ...
  </TopicConfiguration>
   ...
</NotificationConfiguration>
```

Comment: The creation of the NotificationConfiguration is the problem. When I try to create it for the existing bucket, I receive the "Unable to validate the following destination configurations" error, but when I try to create it for the new bucket, everything works. I'm using the console UI.

Comment: It sounds like you may not have permission to make that change to the existing bucket, is your account the creator or owner of the bucket?